# ArchLinux: Missing `eth0` after following tutorial

Tags: networking, arch-linux

I've had my machine running with ArchLinux for the past 4 months working great. I wanted to make my own custom Arch ISO following this tutorial: http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/blog/create-custom-arch-linux-distro-0131002/

I got to the end of step 2 and was installing my own packages when I gave up and exited.

Now, everything was working fine. System still running and `ifconfig` shows `eth0` at this point. I rebooted the machine and did an `ifconfig` and `eth0` was gone (even after running `dhcpcd`).

So I popped in an Arch live CD and did a `ifconfig` after running `dhcpcd` and `eth0` was listed and able to ping google.com.

I'm pretty sure that this line:

```
mknod /dev/loop0 b 7 0
```

is what might have screwed me over here. The loopback interface is the only thing listed in `ifconfig`.

Comment: loop0 should have nothing to do with it. use dmesg to see if eth0 got detected, or renamed.

Comment: `loop0` is a loopback *block device*, not a network interface.